# HTML vs PHP vs cgi

Tags: php, html, cgi

I seem to have run in to a problem with HTML vs PHP vs cgi- look at this:

```
Purchase <a href="http://blazeaudio.com/cgi-bin/shoppingcart.php?rep=1&se1=1">RipEditBurn Plus</a> for $59.95.
```

It doesn't seem to work! It goes to cgi.

Comment: Why is your `.php` file in your `cgi-bin` folder? Also, have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far to solve the problem? Please attempt something, then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: That doesn't work in my machine....

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to config the iis or tomcat .visit Click [here](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-configuration)!